# Colocar uma linha em um UITabBarItem?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

Como colocar uma linha na parte de baixo de um UITabBarButton assim como ocorre nesta imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém essa linha somente deve surgir no botão selecionado.

Comment: Aqui explica muito bem... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33667481/add-a-line-as-a-selection-indicator-to-a-uitabbaritem-in-swift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazê-lo com adicionar imagem personalizada, que será criado em seu código, para selectionIndicatorImage no seu objeto UITabBar. Por exemplo, você pode criar extensão para a classe UIImage como este:

```
extension UIImage {
    func createSelectionIndicator(color: UIColor, size: CGSize, lineWidth: CGFloat) -> UIImage {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0)
        color.setFill()
        UIRectFill(CGRectMake(0, size.height - lineWidth, size.width, lineWidth))
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image
    }
}
```

E chamar isto no seu primeiro ViewController carregado, algo como isto.

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let tabBar = self.tabBarController!.tabBar
        tabBar.selectionIndicatorImage = UIImage().createSelectionIndicator(UIColor.blueColor(), size: CGSizeMake(tabBar.frame.width/CGFloat(tabBar.items!.count), tabBar.frame.height), lineWidth: 2.0)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

E o resultado vai ficar parecido com isto.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]